# How to execute an external program from within Node.js?

Tags: node.js, command, exec

Is it possible to execute an external program from within node.js? Is there an equivalent to Python's `os.system()` or any library that adds this functionality?

Comment: You want to use the `child_process` module. See [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), which provides several clear examples of various use cases.

Answer (score 151):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('pwd', function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
  // result
});
```

Comment: What's the best way to act on a result of the child process. Example... if the process returns an exit code 0, and I want to call a different method, I seem to run into a plethora of errors.

Comment: @continuousqa -- This answer is 4 years old.  If you are having issues, please post a new question on SO and reference this one if necessary.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@graeme_boy/how-to-optimize-cpu-intensive-work-in-node-js-cdc09099ed41#.se7f974h7) has good tips on using `child_process`.

Answer (score 88):

exec has memory limitation of buffer size of 512k. In this case it is better to use spawn.
With spawn one has access to stdout of executed command at run time

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var prc = spawn('java',  ['-jar', '-Xmx512M', '-Dfile.encoding=utf8', 'script/importlistings.jar']);

//noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
prc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
prc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    var str = data.toString()
    var lines = str.split(/(\r?\n)/g);
    console.log(lines.join(""));
});

prc.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('process exit code ' + code);
});
```

Comment: I took this code and it fails to show output of spawned process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302350/node-js-cant-get-output-of-spawned-process

Comment: @PaulVerest: Your output may have been in `stderr` rather than `stdout`. In my case though the `close` is never coming ...

Comment: what about stdin? is it possible to send data to the process?

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way is:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process")
exec('yourApp').unref()
```

**unref** is necessary to end your process without waiting for "yourApp"

Here are the exec [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Answer (score 5):

From the Node.js documentation:

> Node provides a tri-directional popen(3) facility through the ChildProcess class.

See http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/child_processes.html

Answer (score 1):

Using import statements with utils promisify:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import utils from 'util';

const execute = utils.promisify(exec);
console.log(await execute('pwd'));
```