# Is there a way to run R code from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, r

I am working on a project which requires some R code to be run for some data analysis. The project is primarily in JavaScript, and I need a way to run R code from JS. My research has not found any good way to do it yet. Is there any way to do so?

Also, I have next to no experience with R (another person is supplying the R code).

Comment: Do you use IE or other browsers? Internet Explorer does have a mechanism to script Windows from javascript, but you would have to adjust your security settings ....then using `Rscript.exe` you can run `yourScript.R` like this `var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');shell .Run("Rscript yourScript.R arg1");`

Comment: Right now, I'm developing in Chrome. I don't think I will easily be able to switch.

Comment: This is Javascript *on the browser* right? This is for a web client? That's important, because these days JS isn't just a web client language, and can run as a fully-privileged language (see node.js) on a machine as well as a sandboxed language in a web browser.

Comment: Do you already know about shiny? http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/  If you don't know about it, I would check it out before trying spending too much time doing things "the hard way".  Especially notice the tutorial pages on using html directly, and the bit about dynamic ui; http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, although I may move the backend over to node.js in the future, it is currently a client-side browser-based project.

Comment: There is `node-Rstats` if you're using node: https://github.com/Planeshifter/node-Rstats

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're ok with having the R code run on a server, then you should take a look at [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/). It provides a REST API and corresponding JavaScript library for sending R code to the server and getting the results back. In particular, it takes care of the security problems that can arise from running R as a server (R code can run arbitrary shell commands, among other things). There are public demo instances that you can use to try it out, and [this page](https://github.com/abresler/ramnathv.github.io/blob/master/posts/making-rcharts-live-app/index.md) provides a simple tutorial.

Comment: the link is broken!

Comment: Link is broken, here is backup https://github.com/abresler/ramnathv.github.io/blob/master/posts/making-rcharts-live-app/index.md

Answer (score 13):

How about [R-node](https://github.com/elijah/r-node) ?

I think another alterative would be to use **node.js** as a server (http://nodejs.org/) and call R from within as a child process, search the Node.js API docs for specifics.

Also look at this for confirmation: [Is it possible to execute an external program from within node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js)

Note: **node** can run any JS script(s) you may have, they don't necessarily need to be node-specific.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of R-node?

Comment: Sure, I haven't personally tried it, but this is quoted directly from gitourious, you just needed to click that tiny more... link :) 

////
R-Node is a web front-end to the statistical analysis package R. 
Using this front-end, you can from any web browser connect to an R instance running on a remote (or local) server, and interact with it, sending commands and receiving the responses.

In particular, graphing commands such as plot() and hist() will > execute in the browser, drawing the graph as an SVG image.

Comment: Always better to have the info here on SO, and even better in the answer itself. Web pages have a nasty habit of moving or being edited. Looks like a useful package though so hopefully it'll stick around.

Comment: I think that this will probably be my best shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means the best way, but I was able to do the following for my own Javascript+R project (silly.r is an R script that lives in the "r" directory). I basically ran the R code as a terminal command from my express server:

```js
app.get('/sfunction', function (req, res) {
    exec('Rscript r/silly.r this is a test', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
        }
        else if (stderr) {
            console.log(stderr);
            res.send(stderr);
        }
        else if (stdout) {
            console.log("RAN SUCCESSFULLY");
            res.sendfile("savedoutput/test.json");
        }
    });
});
```

The code is from lines 167-182 from here: https://github.com/ngopal/VisualEncodingEngine/blob/master/jsserver/app.js