# Running R and packages on GCP cloud function

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I have been using AWS Lambda to execute some R code by packaging the dependencies (CRAN Packages) and deploying it along with AWS Lambda.
This helps me parrallelise running a small chunk of R code over huge set of data compared to running it on an instance.
I have referred to this article [GENOMICS ON AWS LAMBDA](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/)
The Lambda executes using RPY2 on Python.

I am exploring possibility of running the R code on Google Cloud Functions as I am using Big Query for querying some data.

I see that Google Cloud Functions now supports only NodeJS. There are few ways to execute R script from NodeJS.
[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/r-script)
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665565/is-there-a-way-to-run-r-code-from-javascript)

But I need to package all the necessary packages to run my R code also. On AWS I did it by using a AWS AMI to install all R packages then create a Zip which would get deployed.

I wonder if someone has tried running R code with packages on Google Cloud functions.

Comment: Have you tries doing this and ran into any issues? You should be able to deploy your cloud function with as many files as you'd like, up to the [deployment size limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits), though it might be necessary to include them in your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files). Thus there should in theory be no issue with deploying your R packages with the Cloud Function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using AppEngine, or containers, for your task rather than CloudFunctions.  There are some suggestions for how to do it here: http://code.markedmondson.me/4-ways-schedule-r-scripts-on-google-cloud-platform/  and on Compute Engine here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-r-at-scale

Comment: We have been doing it on Compute but using Lambda has been lowcost and much quicker..but when we tried the same on GC Function we found that the cold start takes a long time compared to AWS Lambda..hence till GCP catches up Lambda is good..only advantage GCP Functions had was the package size of 500MB vs 250MB which now has been increased to 500MB on Lambda ..We can spawn almost 3000 Lambdas at a time which can help us run large parallel data operations provided they are less than 5mins..for this kind of performace we will need much more compute power if we use AppEngine/Containers /compute..

Comment: @AnantBhandarkar, which one do you think is worth the trouble - Going through Rpy2 process (or) rewriting my R code in Python? Thanks.