# How can I use or convert R language script/program to Android application using Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, r, kotlin

I'm writing an application for Android devices and want to execute R script from Java/Kotlin. Is there any way I can do so or is there any tool that can help me in converting R language into the Java/Kotlin?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801017/5710872  Or you can run the R file on a server.

Comment: For your second question ... converting any language to another is usually dependent on the complexity and specifics of the code. Regardless, I don't know of any tools to convert R into something else, though it's been asked many times. (I'll be interested to hear if there are any `R-to-*` converters out there :-)

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24288062/5710872