# How to use python script in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, cappuccino

Can someone help me?
I have a project on Node.js(Cappuccino framework), and I must to use with the project my Python script.
How to do this deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not consult Google before asking. Searching for 'node.js execute python' got me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js). I'm guessing this is what you want.

I'm guessing because you're not being very clear. Next time be more specific.

Comment: I know about child-processes. But, this app creat on cappuccino framework. And I have problem becouse of this.
app.js has some redirect to the cappuccino.
And child-process don't work, or i do something wrong.

Comment: I think, app.js must has something like this: app.get('/', routes.index);
But with another script(which call python script, with some parameters,as child-process) instead of index.js.