# Node.js can't get output of spawned process

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

This code get output of [spawned process](http://www.nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). What is wrong? node version is v0.10.22

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var what = 'java';
var spawned = spawn(what,  ['-version']);

console.log('starting `'+what+' -version`');

spawned.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
spawned.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

spawned.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('process exit code ' + code);
});

var whendone = function() {
    console.log('done');
};
setTimeout(whendone,5000);
```

As you can see I even added some timeout to wait for a launched process to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java -version` writes to `stderr`.

Comment: Yes, and as for `node`, it needs `--version` otherwise enters REPL. Those were example I tried.