# Programmatically both start and kill a web browser using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

How can I programmatically both start and kill a web browser using Node.js?

Pseudo-ish code like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// This opens a browser and returns control to terminal, but optimally
// the process should run in the foreground and exit on ctrl-c.
spawn('open', ['http://www.stackoverflow.com']);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  // Kill the opened browser here
});
```

Comment: You're going to have to show the relevant code if you wish to get answers here.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a suggestion on which to library to use, which is not what StackOverflow is for

Comment: If you are looking for a package to do this like Karma Test Runner does, Juan Mendes is correct.  If you are trying to implement similar behavior in your own code, Jonast92 is correct (and Karma Test Runner's code seems like a good place to look for clues how to go about it).  Please clarify which is the case.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031763/doing-a-cleanup-action-just-before-node-js-exits for how to do things on `ctrl-c`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've removed references to other libs from the question, and added some code that hopefully clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "spawn"

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Also, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099450/4130451

To Kill: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal