# How do I deploy code directly from github to parse.

Tags: parse-platform, github

Right now I am deploying code to the parse cloud via the command line tool. Is it possible for parse to automatically deploy changes on my github master branch? If so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with Parse alone.

However, you could use [Github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) and the [Parse CLI](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#command-line) to configure your own setup with a server (used to deploy). The overview is:

1) Set up Parse CLI on your server so that you can run commands like `parse deploy`

2) Set up your server to listen for Github webhooks. e.g., http://yoursite.com/githubWebhook listen for POST requests.

3) When your endpoint receives the POST from github (confirmed via the secret included in the Github POST payload), you can run a script that executes the `parse deploy` command on your server.

Here's an [example project in Node.js](https://github.com/rvagg/github-webhook-handler) that shows how to set up the handler for Github webhooks. And here's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js) describing how to execute commands in node.

Let me know if you need anymore clarification.