# Node: Run a Java file and return response

Tags: java, node.js

Is it possible to run a Java file from a node application, and get the response of it? For example something as simple as:

```
package com.app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println('Hello World');
    }
}
```

And I want to get the response `Hello World`

Comment: Your node app would have to compile that class, then sure, you can capture the standard output just like any other process...

Comment: I am curious to see your use case here, if you don't mind

Comment: There is another question and answer like this in here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js

Comment: Run the Java file with `.spawn()` or `.exec()` like you would run any external process and then examine `stdout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Compile you java file
2. execute it by node?  in this way

```html
let childProcess = require('child_process').spawn(
      'java', ['-jar', 'yureJavaFile.jar']
    );

childProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

childProcess.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hello Sir i too have same problem but in my case on running of jar it accepts multiple inputs from jar ...how to get this from node

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do more complex interaction between java and node you may want to look at [node-java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java). It allows you to create and handle Java objects in a node application and call Java functions in external java class files or jars.

```
var ArrayList = java.import('java.util.ArrayList');
var list3 = new ArrayList();
list3.addSync('item1');
list3.equalsSync(list1); // true
```