# Opening Adobe with a JavaScript command

Tags: javascript, scripting, applescript, adobe

Hello I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to launch an Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator application through a JavaScript script.

I know this is possible with the use of AppleScript ...

AppleScript example :

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
     activate
end tell
```

is there a way to do the same with JavaScript script ?

Please note that I am would like to execute this script file from a server via NodeJs child process and not from a browser

Comment: i don't think you can do this from browser

Comment: not from browser but from an external script that can be executed

Comment: Apparently there is a `aam://` URL protocol for Adobe applications, perhaps it's possible to use that somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to execute an external program from within node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js)

Comment: not a duplicate .... My question is specific to the script that is going to tell Adobe what operations to perform, NOT how to run the script @KarlReid

Comment: You should say that in the question then- your AppleScript example just shows opening the application, not controlling it. In that case, maybe look at this : https://github.com/dtinth/JXA-Cookbook - it seems there is a JS interface for AppleScript, so maybe that is what you want. But I'm not aware of any cross-platform way of scripting application behaviour like with AppleScript.