# Electron : How to call COM object of all OS windows/macOS/Linux like Excel.Application/ Outlook.Application from node.js with electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

How to call a COM object like Excel.Application and Outlook from node.js with electron?

I need to open outlook email client in cross-platform like macOS, Windows, and Linux.

I found win32ole and Winax but these npm packages support only windows OS, not macOS and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to open the client, probably you just need to spawn the proper executable on each platform. By the way, even with COM, I don't think there is a strategy for start the client, you have a strategy to communicate with it. And, as far as I know, COM is just for windows. In order to spawn an executable you can found useful this other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5775088/566608)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Felice, Actually, I want to open the Outlook email client installed on macOS as well as in Windows using electron js (node js ) application. Is there any way to do it in macOS?