# Handling array returned by c program in nodeJs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, c, express

I have compiled a `C` program (**array.out** compiled from **array.c** in linux) which returns a pointer to an array of doubles.

**array.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double* main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double *arr;
    arr = (double *)calloc((3), (unsigned)(sizeof(double)));
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[3] = 30;
    return arr;
}
```

I also have a running express nodejs server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

Is there a way to call that `c` program (**array.out**) and handle its response(`arr`) in express nodeJs server?

Comment: yeah, through a http server .. notwithstanding the general error noted below

Comment: The `main` in C cannot return an array of double. It **has** to return an `int` that is passed back to the shell as result code.

Comment: You can make an [C++ addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_c_addons)

Comment: You can write your C program to output the array of double to stdout and the from node.js execute that program and grab the output. See [How to execute an external program from within node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/how-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js).

Comment: `sizeof(...)` already returns an unsigned type (`size_t`), there's absolutely no need to cast to `unsigned int`. In worst case, you might even cut off size information (imagine 16-bit unsigned int and *huge* struct with more than 65k bytes). Admitted, that's rather of theoretical nature, but still the cast actually is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `child_process` module with the `exec` method

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const res = exec("./array", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // console.log({ error, stdout, stderr });
    const myResult = stdout.split(' ').map(e => parseFloat(e));
    console.log(myResult);
});
```

---

On the other hand, you need **to output the value** for node to handle it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double *arr;
    arr = (double *)calloc((3), (unsigned)(sizeof(double)));
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[2] = 30;
    printf("%f %f %f", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not enough: standard output has to be captured.

Comment: I'm just aswering this question here `Is there a way to call that c program (array.out)`, the anwser on NodeJS side is `child_process`, if your question is `can I trigger a function on my C program with NodeJS?` the answer is yes, by handling arguments and passing that argument to the execSync command

Comment: It appears pretty obvious to me that user wants to retrieve information from the child process in the parent one: *'which returns a pointer to an array of doubles'*. So a complete answer needs to cover that part as well.

Comment: Updated. I missed the part where the main function didn't have an output

Comment: Sorry, I was on other questions, should be good now

Comment: Please update the answer not to return the double array, that's not one of the legal signatures for `main` functions, standard *requires* to return `int`.

Comment: Done, returns int 0 now

Comment: @savageGoat so there's no other way in which I can collect the arr elements without printing them?

Comment: @kapil-sarwat the only way I see is to run the program that dumps the result into a file and you read that new file. Other than that I don't see how else it could be done, but I'd gladly take any suggestion as I think this is a good question and I'm actually interested if there's another way

Comment: @kapilsarwat There are, but they aren't as simple: pipelines, sockets, shared memory, ... – data might even be passed as binary, but that's only valid if both C and python use the same representation for doubles (C uses host's representation which usually is IEEE 754, would assume the same for python, but not sure about!).

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer as [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67847773/1312382) is already given by [savageGoat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15842737/savagegoat), but some additional hints on writing better C code:

```
double *arr;
arr = (double *)calloc((3), (unsigned)(sizeof(double)));
```

Please skip all those unnecessary parentheses, they just make the code harder to read. Assignment *can* occur directly with declaration, but that's rather a matter of personal preference:

```
double *arr = (double *)calloc(3, (unsigned)sizeof(double));
```

The cast to `unsigned int` is unnecessary, `sizeof` already evaluates to an unsigned type (`size_t`). Actually the cast even is technically wrong, as you  might cut off size information that way: Imagine 16-bit unsigned int and a *huge* struct with more than 65k bytes – admitted, that's rather of theoretical nature, but still the cast is not correct.

Additionally you are assigning values afterwards anyway, so zero-initializing, which `calloc` does, is just unnecessary ballast, so prefer `malloc` in *this* case:

```
double *arr = (double *)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
```

Now there's still a memory leak left! Sure, the OS will clean up that for you, as the process terminates anyway, but get used right from the start to considering to free any dynamically allocated memory right at the point of doing so (or even before...). Otherwise you *will* run into memory leaks on longer running processes.

Even better: Allocate the array on the stack, if not too large for; in this case, you even can initialize it right away:

```
double arr[] = { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 }; // size is calculated by compiler
```

Finally, in this case you do not need the array at all:

```
printf("%f %f %f
```

Actually, you don't even need a dynamically allocated array at all:

```
printf("%f %f %f", 10.0, 20.0, 30.0);
```

Just make sure to use the *correct* literals (`10, 20, 30` would provide three `int` values, which would be accepted as well by the compiler, but provoke undefined behaviour as not matching the required type for the format specifiers).