# How to install additional dependencies through VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension that is going to use another tool.
so my VSCode extension needs that third-party tool installed on the system to work.
so how can I install that dependency and add it to the system environment path when any user will install my extension?

Comment: Your extension is no different from a typical Node.js console application, so I wonder why it cannot install the dependency and configure the system. You just need to learn JS/TS and Node.js.

Comment: yes you mean I should add packages to package.json, right? 
but I want to install a exe software and set its path. because only after that my extension will work

Comment: "I want to install a exe software and set its path" are super easy to achieve by executing external commands, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/how-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js

Comment: I don't know why are you dissing me at this point when I am just seeking some information. but anyway. I know how to run external commands and but I am not getting how to do it automatically when some user will install my Exension.

Comment: "how to do it automatically when some user will install my Exension". It is impossible as the installation of an extension is just unzipping the contents. You have to use code in `activate` to perform installation of any dependencies.